# Persistent collections and standard collection interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm implementing a persistent collection - for the sake of argument, let's say it's a singly-linked list, of the style common in functional languages.

```
class MyList<T>
{
    public T Head { get; }
    public MyList<T> Tail { get; }

    // other various stuff
    // . . .
}
```

It seems natural to have this class implement `ICollection<T>`, since it can implement all the normal behavior one would expect of an `ICollection<T>`, at least in broad strokes.  But there is a lot of mismatch between this class's behavior and `ICollection<T>`.  For example, the signature of the `Add()` method

```
void Add(T item);  // ICollection<T> version
```

assumes that the addition will be performed as a side-effect that mutates the collection. But this is a persistent data structure, so Add() should instead create a new list and return it.

```
MyList<T> Add(T item);  // what we really want
```

It seems the best way to resolve this is to just create the version we want, and also generate a non-functional explicit implementation of the version defined in the interface.

```
void ICollection<T>.Add(T item) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
public MyList<T> Add(T item) { return new MyList<T>(item, this); }
```

But I have a few concerns about that option:

1. Will this be confusing to users?  I envision scenarios where someone is working with this class, and finds that calling Add() on it sometimes raises an exception, and sometimes runs but doesn't modify the list as would normally be expected for an ICollection, depending on the type information associated with the reference being used?
2. Following on (1), the implementation of `ICollection<T>`'s `IsReadOnly` should presumably return true.  But that would seem to conflict with what is implied in other spots where Add() is being used with instances of the class.
3. Is (2) resolved in a non-confusing way by following the explicit implementation pattern again, with the new version returning `false` and the explicit implementation returning `true`? Or does this just make it even worse by falsely implying that `MyList<T>`'s `Add()` method is a mutator?
4. Or would it be better to forget trying to use the existing interface and just create a separate `IPersistentCollection<T>` interface that derives from `IEnumerable<T>` instead?

**edit** I changed the name of the class, and switched over to using ICollection.  I wanted to focus on the object's behavior and how it relates to the interface.  I just went with the cons list as a simple example. I appreciate the advice that if I were to implement a cons list I should try and come up with a less-confusing name and, should avoid implementing IList because that interface is intended for fast random access, but they are somewhat tangential issues.

What I intended to ask about is what others think about the tension between the semantics of read-only (or immutable) collections that are baked into the Framework, and persistent collections which implement equivalent behavior to what is described by the interface, only functionally rather than through mutating side effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will implementing `IList<T>` be confusing?

Yes. Though there are situations in which an implementation of `IList<T>` throws -- say, when you are attempting to resize the list but its implementation is an array -- I would find it quite confusing to have an `IList<T>` that could be mutated in no way *and* did not have fast random access.

> Should I implement a new `IPersistentList<T>`?

That depends on whether anyone will use it.  Are consumers of your class likely to have a half-dozen different implementations of `IPL<T>` to choose from? I see no point in making an interface that is implemented by only one class; just use the class.

> WPF's ItemsControl can get better performance if its ItemsSource is an `IList<T>` instead of an `IEnumerable<T>`.

But your persistent linked list will not have fast random access anyway.

Comment: True - but what about a structure that is persistent *and* has (relatively) fast random access?  I was hoping to focus on the interface-related questions I asked, and ignore issues arising from a particular class's implementation.

Answer (score 3):

It would make more sense to me to make a new `IPersistentList<T>` (or `IImmutableList<T>` since "persistent" sounds to me like the data is saved off somewhere.) interface since, really, it's different behavior than what is expected of an `IList<T>`. Classes that implement `IList<T>` should be mutable IMHO.

Oh, and of course, I'd avoid using the class name `List<T>` since it's already part of the framework.

Comment: Immutability is built into the definition of `IList<T>` - there's an `IsReadOnly` property, the documentation defines what should happen if a mutator is called on a read-only IList<T>, and there are framework classes such as `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Comment: @Sean U: I agree with itsme86. If you really want to implement IList<T> and other well known collection interfaces then you can still add the necessary members, but you'll have to throw exceptions when mutation methods are called, as you outline in your question.